# Synchronize directories (backup) solution that can read MFT for changes

Tags: backup, file-synchronization, synchronization, ntfs

I'm going to back up a partition (or some folders on a partition), but it has large enough directory structure so I don't want to wait until it recursively scans for file changes through all the disk when I'll be synchronizing files next time.

There is software that can insanely quick search for files on the whole partition using MFT, now I need this ability for making an incremental backup. Is there such a backup software that makes use of it?

For Windows XP, preferably Open Source.

Comment: Is there some rule against requesting software recommendations for outdated and insecure operating systems?

Answer (score -1):

Two MFT opensource project

- [DivConq MFT](https://github.com/Gadreel/divconq)

> DivConq MFT is a free, open-source Managed File Transfer project. It
>   currently includes a secure file transfer server and a secure gateway.
>   It may also be extended to handle custom use cases.

- [World of Waarp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/waarp/)

> Waarp is a project that provides among other an open source massive
>   file transfer monitor in Java. Its goal is to unify several protocols
>   (FTP, FTPS, SSH, HTTP and proprietary protocols) in an efficient and
>   secured way. Its purpose is to enable bridging between several
>   protocols and to enable dynamic pre or post action on transfer or
>   other commands. Currently FTP(S) and efficient and secure R66
>   protocols are implemented. HTTP is supported but not yet in production
>   release.

Comment: I don't see any confirmation that it reads MFT on NTFS partitions.

Comment: i change sites and informations

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help, but that is wrong MFT. I was talking about NTFS Master File Table. Here it is explained how it works for search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_(software)#How_it_works I'm looking for backup software based on similar principles.